# Insert into a unordered map changes the share ptr to null

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In the below example after fetching the value from the first map and inserting into the second map the shared ptr become null. Even the destructor is not called. I cannot understand what exactly is wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

class Test
{
    public:
        Test(){}
        ~Test(){}

        int test;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Test> Test_ptr;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Test_ptr> TestMap;

int main()
{
    TestMap map1, map2;
    std::string key("abc");
    Test_ptr ptr(new Test);
    map1.insert(TestMap::value_type(key, ptr));

    TestMap::iterator iter = map1.find(key);
    if (iter != map1.end())
    {
        map2.insert(*iter);
        if (iter->second == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "after insert the shared ptr becomes null"  << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

> g++ -std=c++11 testsharedptr.cpp -o testsharedptr
>
> gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)

Comment: When I compiled and ran this program, it did not print anything.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/oDWBab).

Comment: 3 for 3 as not reproducible.  Can you provide the compiler and command line you used to build?  Maybe there's something in your specific build environment?

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 testsharedptr.cpp  -o testsharedptr

Comment: gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)

Comment: Seldom case when somebody published mcve and people -1 the question. What's wrong with you?

Comment: @Nithesh Add compiler details and command line argument to the question.

Comment: @Slava in this case people believed the "V" was missing from "MCVE". That's an unfortunate side effect of a bug that only happens with a particular version of a compiler.

Answer (score 6):

I was not able to reproduce the issue using GCC 4.9.2.  However, I was able to reproduce it using GCC 4.8.1.

The root cause is a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57619) in the libstdc++ implementation of the following [`std::unordered_map::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) overload:

```
template< class P >
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( P&& value );
```

The GCC 4.8.1 implementation is

```
template<typename _Pair, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<value_type, _Pair&&>::value>::type>
std::pair<iterator, bool>
insert(_Pair&& __x)
{ return _M_h.insert(std::move(__x)); }
```

while the GCC 4.9.2 implementation is

```
template<typename _Pair, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<value_type, _Pair&&>::value>::type>
std::pair<iterator, bool>
insert(_Pair&& __x)
{ return _M_h.insert(std::forward<_Pair>(__x)); }
```

In the GCC 4.8.1 case, the map entry you're passing is being moved to `map2` rather than copied.  Thus, the `std::shared_ptr` from `map1` gets set to `nullptr` as a side effect of the move.

If possible, I would recommend upgrading to GCC 4.8.2 or later, in which this bug has been fixed.

If you are unable to upgrade, using a `const_iterator` will yield the expected behavior:

```
TestMap::const_iterator iter = map1.find(key);
```

By using a `const_iterator`, you are forcing this overload to be called:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
```

which does not modify the passed value.

Comment: Yet another reason to use `const_iterator` when yo do not plan to modify a container